# tkinter matplotlib error _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist in Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to run following code, which run successfully... but when I am trying to import matplotlib it give error  ---->  _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist while using PyCharm, but with python IDLE it works without error.

```
import cv2
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime
import openpyxl
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def show_frames():
    im = cap.read()[1]
    Image1= cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(Image1)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
    label.imgtk = imgtk
    label.configure(image=imgtk)
    label.after(20, show_frames)

def capture():
    I = cap.read()[1]
    save_name = str(datetime.datetime.now().today()).replace(":", " ") + ".jpg"
    cv2.imwrite(save_name, I)


 #here creating window and GUI
 win = Tk()
 win.geometry("1200x650")
 win.title('Portable Optical Spectrometer')

 L2 = Label(win,text = " Camera  ",font=("times new roman",20,"bold"),bg="white",fg="red").grid(row=0, column=0)
 L2 = Label(win,text = " Spectrum Graph ",font=("times new roman",20,"bold"),bg="white",fg="red").grid(row=0, column=2)
 label =Label(win)
 label.grid(row=1, column=0)
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 show_frames()
 B1 = Button(win,text="Capture",font=("Times new roman",20,"bold"),bg="white",fg="red",command=capture()).grid(row=3, column=0, )
 B1 = Button(win,text="Analysis",font=("Times new roman",20,"bold"),bg="white",fg="red",).grid(row=4, column=0)

 L1 = Label(win,text = "Detected Material is:  ",font=("times new roman",20,"bold"),bg="white",fg="red").grid(row=4, column=1)
 Output = Text(win, height = 3,width = 25,bg = "light cyan").grid(row=4, column=2)


 win.mainloop()
 cap.release()
```

can someone suggest how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the PhotoImage is poorly documented, but it seems that if you have more than one Tkinter root then you need to specify *which* root that the PhotoImage should use — with the "master" argument. This applies to both the basic Tkinter PhotoImage and Pillow's ImageTk wrapper. Matplotlib usually uses Tk as its backend so that will usually invoke the problem. IDLE also uses Tk so it's anybody's guess what that combination would do.

See the following example. If the "master=" argument is removed from either of the two PhotoImage creation lines below then it errors out.

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

photimg = tk.PhotoImage(width=100,height=100, master=root)
tk.Label(root, image=photimg).pack()

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
pilimg = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(200, 200))
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pilimg, master=root)
tk.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack()
```